# Mathematica presentations - will the Apple infra-red remote change slides?

Tags: slideshows

I have a presentation to do and i am thinking about using *Mathematica* instead of Powerpoint/Keynote as i have quite a few animations i would like to show. When using *Mathematica* in slideshow mode, will the Apple remote work and let me move between slides ?

Comment: you mean [this one](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT3176/HT3176-2.jpg) I suppose. Not the iPhone app...

Comment: Yes. I mean apple remote so that when giving presentation i can be standing up and not need to mess around with laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried it out on an older iMac and an old white plastic Apple remote (last sold in 2009, apparently). Yes, it works. You have to hold the Forward/Back buttons down, rather than click. But Mathematica seems to detect these actions and advances to the next slide, or goes back to the previous one. I'd rather go for something wireless, myself, but if IR works, go for it.